# Change Media Library thumbnails for non-image files to include the post title instead of the filename?

Tags: media-library, thumbnails

[image: Lots and lots of PDF's]

We are migrating an outdated custom CMS to Wordpress and all of the files have a corresponding title which is great, but Wordpress chose to show the filename, by default, in the grid view, which sucks, because all the files have alphanumeric names which means the client will have to click on every single file and view the title field to see if that is the file that they are looking for. It does not help that the search field does not return anything at all when searching by the title.

Can somebody point me in the right direction as to which hook I can use to alter these thumbnail captions?

Comment: I got the search form to work within the media library but it would still be cool to change the filename to the file's post title.